# T4 Templates: Import namespace in host assembly

Tags: c#, t4

All,

I have a T4 Template

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Windows.Forms" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="MyLibrarysRootNameSpace.SomeNamespace" #>
/*Rest of template follows*/
```

I'm trying to get the last line to import so that I can easily resuse this template in other projects, but I seem to be missing something.  Is what I am trying to do possible?  If so, how?

Comment: Neither the `System.Core` nor the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly contains the namespace `MyLibrarysRootNameSpace.SomeNamespace`, so it's obvious that the import fails. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: MyLibrarysRootNameSpace.SomeNamespace refers to a Namespace that contains a class definition within my own code.  It's part of the host project, and not part of any System namespace (that's why I have it beginning with the word My)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Import just adds a using statement, it does not reference the assembly.  T4's referenced assembly set is completely divorced from the project that is hosting the template.

If you want to bring in your hosting project's assembly then you need an assembly directive to do it. Something like the following:

<#@ assembly name="$(TargetPath)" #>

Note that you are introducing a build loop here, so the project will need manual intervention to build until it has produced a DLL once, so make sure you only generate partials that are optional or can always use the previous checked in version.

Comment: I'll mark this as answer, even though as you said it causes a build loop.  Turns out what I thought I needed for the type comparison wasn't all that important.

Comment: *Import just adds a using statement*. To be clear, it imports a namespace; it doesn't write a using statement to the output file. (Probably what you meant.)

Comment: It adds a using statement to the intermediate code that gets compiled and executed to generate the output file.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly:

Copy-paste the first 2 snippets [from there](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/blog/walking-the-visual-studio-code-model-with-t4-template.html) to get the EnvDTE object model for the project that contains the T4:

```
<#@ assembly name="EnvDte" #>
<#
    var visualStudio = ( this.Host as IServiceProvider )
        .GetService( typeof( EnvDTE.DTE ) ) as EnvDTE.DTE;
    var project = visualStudio.Solution
        .FindProjectItem( this.Host.TemplateFile )
        .ContainingProject as EnvDTE.Project;
#>
```

Then, use [the method from there](http://fabianfernandezdotnet.blogspot.com/2011/09/envdte-project-get-default-namespace.html) to obtain the default namespace of that project:

```
// project is of type: EnvDTE.Project
string strDefaultNamespace = project.Properties.Item( "DefaultNamespace" )
    .Value.ToString();
```

Then, use `strDefaultNamespace` value however your like.

Comment: Kind of.  I was hoping to have it more as a directive then a string literal.

Comment: This will get the namespace, but the assembly is still not referenced.

Comment: You could use System.IO.StreamWriter class to write a single-line ImportDefaultNamespace.tt text file, then use `<#@ include` directive to include that file.
However, I do not see any value in doing that. Copy-pasting source code files across project is a rarely a good practice per se (a shared assemblies usually work better), but you also have to edit the namespace in the source code files you have copy-pasted?

Comment: Or, if you don’t have shared code/interfaces, you won’t be able to reuse the T4 because it won’t compile. Automatic namespace import gives you nothing unless the namespace contains the classes you call from your T4 source code.
Or, if in the T4 you only use reflection on your data types and not calling them directly, you don’t need to import any namespaces.

Comment: @GarethJ, you could add reference using the same method. To obtain output path, query "OutputFileName" project property.

Comment: In this case shared assemblies is not an option because my template will be creating partials that are host specific.  As for reflection, I have started down this route, but it's a bit time consuming and presents its own challenges.

Comment: @Soonts, I'm not sure I follow.  Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: I could, but I found out that the type comparison I was trying to do wouldn't have worked anyway, as CodeAttribute is COM and wouldn't match up with System.Attribute.  Basically, what I was doing was building my own version of generated code utilizing attributes (to take care of boiler-plate code for PropertyChanged notification and DependancyProperties).  Inspiration for this project was from Colin Eberhardt (http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/08/declarative-dependency-property-definition-with-t4-dte/) and Olyg Sych...

Comment: http://www.olegsych.com/2008/07/t4-template-for-generating-sql-view-from-csharp-enumeration/

Comment: Colin's approach is pretty good if you use CodeModel to read the code from your projects rather than reflection then you can build some pretty nice solutions,